# Is it possible to create external table without mentioning column in hive

Tags: ddl, hiveql

Is it possible to create external table without mentioning column in hive

CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE table_name(
     )
      ROW FORMAT SERDE ' '

Answer (score 0):

No we cannot. If you want to create a table having schema similar to another table, we can use " CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME LIKE SOURCE_TABLE...." where in you don't mention the schema.